# flutter local notifications multicolor icon

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The icon of notification on Android platform is displayed in grey color. I saw many suggestions such as making [transparent background with white icon](https://clevertap.com/blog/fixing-notification-icon-for-android-lollipop-and-above/) so I could give color I want to. Problem is that my icon has several colors in it. Is there any solution for this?